# push_back() in a 2D vector faults when using a dynamic size

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying something simple.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > computeBuf;
std::vector<int> temp;
computeBuf.push_back(temp);                        // correct
computeBuf.push_back(std::vector<int> (10) );      // correct  
int size = 10;
computeBuf.push_back(std::vector<int> (size) );    // correct
int dynsize = someClass.getValue();
computeBuf.push_back(std::vector<int> (dynsize) ); // fault !!!!!
```

What is it about the variable "dynSize" that crashes the program.
It appears that the compiler needs to know the size of the variable.
Why is that so ??
(PS : someClass.getValue() returns an int)

Comment: We need to see that function.

Comment: `dynsize` can be too large.

Comment: It looks likely that it actually crashs in `getValue` function, or it returns a large garbage value, or a negative value..

Comment: It might be the function not returning a value, or returning some uninitialized value.

Comment: thanks. The fact that both chris and fasked did not point anything wrong with the way I was push_back made me look back at my code. I debugged some more and realized that dynSize was -1.

Answer (score 2):

> I debugged some more and realized that **dynSize was -1.**

The constructor called here is `std::vector::vector( std::size_t )`, which takes an unsigned number. Passing a negative value results in an attempt to allocate a huge vector, which will likely lead to immediate termination.